# SELECT all rows from Table WHERE col1 of one row = col2 of another row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider a subsection of a table:

```
recId|Col1   |Val1  |Col2   |Val2
________________________________________
    1|'Id'   |'1'   |NULL   |NULL  |
    2|'EmpId'|'100' |'Id'   |'1'   |
    3|'EmpId'|'101' |'Id'   |'1'   |
    4|'KeyId'|'1110'|'EmpId'|'100' |
    5|'EmpId'|'101' |'KeyId'|'1111'|
    6|'Id'   |'2'   |NULL   |NULL  |
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to pull all records out of this table that are related to the first row, where Id = @id?

For the sake of this example, let @id = 1.

The output should consist of rows where recId IN (1,2,3,4,5) from the sample table above (Id=1 is shared by a row with EmpId=101, which is shared by a row with KeyId=1111, etc.).

Is this possible?

## Edit:

Thanks to [a comment suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50934663/select-all-rows-from-table-where-col1-of-one-row-col2-of-another-row/50938178#comment88872181_50934838) I've taken a look at recursive common table expressions.

Here's my current [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=ff6ac652c2b810ddcdd1be2fdf058a0f).

```
DECLARE @id integer = 1;

;WITH cte
AS  (
    SELECT n=1,recid,col1,val1,col2,val2 from elbat
        WHERE col1 = 'Id' AND val1 = CAST(@id AS varchar(10))
    UNION ALL
        SELECT n=n+1,r.recid,r.col1,r.val1,r.col2,r.val2
        FROM cte p
    INNER JOIN elbat r
        ON r.col1 = p.col1
            AND r.val1 = p.val1
        OR r.col1 = p.col2
            AND r.val1 = p.val2
        OR r.col2 = p.col1
            AND r.val2 = p.val1
        OR r.col2 = p.col2
            AND r.val2 = p.val2
        WHERE r.recid <> p.recid AND p.n = n AND n<3
    )
SELECT recid,col1,val1,col2,val2
FROM   cte
ORDER BY recid;
```

which results in:

```
recid   col1    val1    col2    val2
________________________________________
1       Id      1       null    null
1       Id      1       null    null
1       Id      1       null    null
2       EmpId   222     Id      1
2       EmpId   222     Id      1
3       EmpId   223     Id      1
3       EmpId   223     Id      1
4       KeyId   4445    EmpId   222
5       EmpId   223     KeyId   4444
```

I'm unsure how to prevent infinite recursion -- I need to exclude results from earlier iterations from the current iteration. Right now, 'n' limits the depth (number of connections through number), but as you can see, it is reusing *all* rows from cte each iteration.

Please assist me in working this out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you need the key

```
SELECT Col1, Val1
FROM Yourtable t1
WHERE Col1 = 'Id'
  AND Val1 = @id
```

Now get all the rows matching that key

```
SELECT *
FROM Yourtable t1
JOIN  ( SELECT Col1, Val1
        FROM Yourtable 
        WHERE col1 = 'Id'
          AND Val1 = @id ) t2
 ON t1.Col2 = t2.Col1
AND t1.Val2 = t2.Val1
```

Using recursive CTE: **[SQL DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=f603515f5c863afce21f99a2c7178da8)**

```
DECLARE @id integer = 1;

;WITH cte AS    (
    SELECT n=1, recid, col1, val1, col2, val2 
    FROM elbat
    WHERE col1 = 'Id' AND val1 = CAST(@id AS varchar(10))

    UNION ALL

    SELECT n=n+1, r.recid, r.col1, r.val1, r.col2, r.val2
    FROM cte p
    JOIN elbat r
      ON r.col2 = p.col1 AND r.val2 = p.val1
)
SELECT n, recid,col1,val1,col2,val2
FROM   cte
ORDER BY recid;
```

Comment: This would only get you rows 1-3, I believe.   To get the full results desired, you'd have to write a recursive version of this.

Comment: @TabAlleman You are right didn't saw that part. Feel free to do your answer. I cant  add more to my answer right now

Comment: @TabAlleman Yeah, I figured it would have to be something like that, but I didn't know how to approach it in SQL.

Comment: Have you seen recursive cte examples?

Comment: I have not, but I will look them up now.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I tried looking at recursive cte, and I'm a bit stuck. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=ff6ac652c2b810ddcdd1be2fdf058a0f).

As a new stackoverflow member, I'm not familiar with the rules; should I post this as a separate question? As an answer to this question and let others comment on it to help? Edit the main question?

Regardless, as you can see, I'm not sure how to exclude duplicates already in cte from the UNION ALL subquery (causing it to recurse infinitely). Right now 'n' limits the depth to not crash, but the results have duplicates.

Comment: I update your dbfiddle with the question data, and was able to get the desire output and didnt have any problem with infinite recursion